# How to reset session variables

Tags: coldfusion

I'm developing an app. in CF10. It's been decided that this app. will be opened through a link that is created in a dot net app.
Users log in & out through the dot net application in order to see the link. When users click on that link they can access the CF application.

This link passes a user id, I'm using this user id to create session.userid
in onSessionStart at application.cfc :

```
  <cfset session.userid = #Trim(URL.userid)#>
```

The problem is, when I log out and log back in as a different user, my previous session.userid still exists. So I have two different session.userids
In order to avoid this I thought I can do the following:

in onSessionStart at application.cfc, I start with sessionIvalidate function:

```
   <cfset sessionInvalidate() />
   <cfset session.userid = #Trim(URL.userid)#>
```

I thought every time the application start application.cfc ColdFsuion has to run through application.cfc then sessionInvalidate function will clean out existing session.userid then a new one is created so if I log in and out as a different users from the same computer then the application still maintains one session.userid.
But unfortunately this approach does not work! I still get the older session while the new session is not created!

What is the best approach to my situation if I can't do it using this logic.
Should I re-set session.userid index.cfm instead?

Comment: *When users click on that link they can access the CF application* Nothing to do with your question, but I hope the CF login process involves more than the presence of a simple URL variable. Otherwise any user could bookmark the link and login under any ID they wish simply by modifying the URL.

Answer (score 4):

`onApplicationStart()` only runs the first time the application is run. You should be running `sessionInvalidate()` as part of your log out process. If that is run correctly, there should be no ColdFusion session variables defined by the previous user ID.

You definitely don't need to run it at the top of `onSessionStart()`. That function does exactly what it's named to do: "run these processes when a new session starts".

Read more [in the CF 10 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html).

You can end a session like this:

```
<cfset StructClear(Session)>
```

or like this if you're using J2EE sessions:

```
<cfset getPageContext().getSession().invalidate()>
```

Although, I'm sure the first example is essentially what `sessionInvalidate()` does.

Also, is this application only accessible via your internal network? So only people from your company can access it? If not, you need to look into implementing a more robust Single Sign On process to bridge access to this one from your other site.

Comment: Please allow me to ask two questions if you don't mind, the first one is, are we still using cflock to create session because I found many blogs, such as from Ray Camden is one of them. It says that after CFMX cflock on session is no longer necessary. I'm confuse now. The second question is how do i know if I'm using J2EE sessions? is there a way to check?

Comment: CFLOCK probably isn' t needed. You'd only be using J2EE sessions if you turned them on in CF Admin.

Comment: Ok thank you! by the way, this is an intranet site, users are within our institutions.

Comment: Both of Use J2EE session variables  and  Enable Session Variables are enabled. So is it enough to use <cfset StructClear(Session)> to clear my session variables?

Comment: @user3779216 - Using structClear has some limitations. See [Ending a session](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d2d) to understand the differences.

Answer (score 3):

With my log out sequence I run 2 separate session destroyers. This way I know the session is destroyed.

```
<cfset structClear( session ) />
<cfset sessionInvalidate()/>
```

I am running CF11 and this works beautifully when my customers log out of my web application.

As for the CFLOCK, depending on your version of CF will depend on if you use it. It's been depreciated in CF11 and when I went to CF11, having it broke my application.